# php Generate monthly sales report from user input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, dynamically-generated

[image: asd]

I'm so lost on this, I would like to generate  the sales from the selected month and year when user clicks `generate reports`. What could be the possible query for this ?? say for example the sales from `November 2013` to `January 2014` and the output would be like

```
MONTH     Sales   Year
November  100     2013
December  200     2013
January   100     2014
```

These are sample data from my DB that might be useful or what could be the possible changes that I should do on my DB to accomplish this ??

```
ORDER_ID  ORDER_DATE(timestamp)  MONTH(varchar)  YEAR(varchar)
  2       2013-11-28 02:01:40     November         2013
  4       2013-12-26 03:01:40     December         2013
  5       2014-01-28 01:01:40     January          2014
```

Need your help badly :'(

Comment: WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN $dropdwon1 AND $dropdown2.You concatenate the values in the drop downs to get a full date.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query should be:

```
SELECT month(ORDER_DATE) AS MONTH, COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS Sales, year(ORDER_DATE) AS Year
FROM your_table
WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
GROUP BY month(ORDER_DATE)
ORDER BY BY your_criteria
```

And in my opinion, the column MONTH and YEAR are not needed, because that date should
be taken from ORDER_DATE using `month` and `year` functions.